# Loading data fast

Tags: android, gson

I have a data (ex. 200 posts) and would like to load it fast so the user doesn't see a progress/preloader every time he enters on this screen. This is what I am doing:

1. If the user is opening the screen for the first time, get first 8 posts, store them (I am storing the JSON as a string into SharedPreferences) and when the user starts scrolling and reaches the 7-th post I am using a pagination (fetching new 8 posts and append them) and so on. **This case is working fine.**
2. If the user already have been on this scree, I load the first 8 posts from SharedPreferences so he can see immediately some results without start fetching new results. When he reaches the bottom - again pagination. The problem is that when clicking between bottom tab bar's items there is a 1s delay opening the tab with the stored data. And when you do it several times it's really annoying. Here's what I am doing:

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       if (isFirstTime) {
           getFirstEight();
           progress.show();
       } else {
           JSONObject data = getStoredJSONFromShared();
           if (data != null) {
               Post[] posts = gson.fromJson(data.getJSONObject("response").get("posts").toString(), Post[].class);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

I create this inside onCreateView because when the user is not seeing the screen for the first time, the data from SharedPreferences is loaded before RecycleView init. Maybe the parsing is slow or I should not create this inside onCreateView.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is show a preloader when the screen is shown to the user even while you are fetching the data from SharedPrefrences.

Load the data in the onResume method, once the data is loaded, you can hide the preloader. This way, at least, the user will be provided with a visual feedback and there won't be that 1 sec lag as you are not loading anything in onCreateView.

Comment: The delay is before opening the new clicked screen. For example you are on item 2, clicking item 1, delay one second, then showing the First fragment. For this reason I think that maybe it takes too much time loading the data and because I do it in the onCreateView it doesn't show the screen immediately.

Comment: Yes, the new clicked screen won't be visible until the view is loaded and that code is under onCreateView. That's why you should keep onCreateView minimal and load your content in onResume method.